# Emacs buffer copy with single stroke

Tags: emacs

assume I have focus on BrokerSyncMasteredRecord.cc. I want to fast copy BrokerSyncMasteredRecord.cc to the left by one stroke(like some hotkeys). the final state in pic 2. Currently, I can only use C-x b and type in a few chars of the buffer name. this is very slow.

NOTE: this should not be another opened replica buffer(e.g., BrokerSyncMasteredRecord.cc[replicated], you know what i mean if you are a emacs user) but exact the same buffer, just show in two different windows

Comment: Doesn't `C-x 3` or `C-x 2`what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I'll just quote the Emacs tutorial (<kbd>f1 t</kbd>) for you:

```
* MULTIPLE WINDOWS
------------------

One of the nice features of Emacs is that you can display more than
one window on the screen at the same time.  (Note that Emacs uses the
term "frames"--described in the next section--for what some other
applications call "windows".  The Emacs manual contains a Glossary of
Emacs terms.)

>> Move the cursor to this line and type C-l C-l.

>> Now type C-x 2 which splits the screen into two windows.
   Both windows display this tutorial.  The editing cursor stays in
   the top window.
```

This basic tutorial is just 1000 lines, almost small enough to use as a capcha
for asking questions about Emacs:)